# Prevent Firebase Analytics from keeping app alive in background?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

We've stumbled upon an issue where Firebase keeps our app alive in the background.

Try this:

1. Create a new single view app
2. run pod init/install, and open your workspace (don't add any pods yet)
3. Add this line of code in AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
   `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in print("ping") })`
4. Run app.

Observe that it will print out "ping" once a second when the app is open.
Now navigate to the home screen, and see that it **stops** printing the message.

5. add `pod 'Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile. (this installs 6.7.0 per now)
6. Pod install
7. Run the app again.

Observe now that your app is suddenly a background app. When navigating home, it will continue printing out this message.

Keep in mind that we haven't added a single line of code to actually implement the framework. It has just been added with cocoapods. We haven't enabled any Background Modes capabilities or anything. Is there a way to prevent Firebase from violating this, or do we have to remove it completely from our project?